# Use regex to reduce a line?

Tags: regex

I have a line such as this:

**andy_1972** * andy@ip.address 0 0 0 0 0 0 **119075** 224 1342751704 1348550270

I want the end result to be the bolded characters, like this:

```
andy_1972 119075
```

I am trying to just trim the line down to the word and the 4th number from the end of the line.

How can I do this using regex? I'm using Notepad++

Comment: Wait, are the characters bolded *in Notepad*, or is that just how you are explaining it to us?  If the former, you have to say what format the underlying file is in (and no, probably a regex won't parse it); if the later, what about 119075 makes it the items you choose to bold?

Comment: I bolded it just in the answer, and I bolded 119075 because it is the 4th number from the end of the line.

Comment: ah.  Edit your question.

Comment: Done, totally forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match the first word and the fourth-from-last number:

```
^(\w+).* (\d+) \d+ \d+ \d+$
```

Comment: How would I use this for Notepad++, or is there a better method?

Comment: It looks like going to the Find/Replace menu, select RegExp mode, and replacing `^(\w+).* (\d+) \d+ \d+ \d+$` with `\1 \2` will do what you want.  I wouldn't know because I don't use DOS, but that's what Google suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In perl-compatible (perl or PCRE) that would be

```
$string = "andy_1972 * andy@ip.address 0 0 0 0 0 0 119075 224 1342751704 1348550270";
$string =~ /^(\w+).* (\d+) \d+ \d+ \d+$/;
print $1 $2;
```

Comment: Did you try this?  I'm pretty sure that would print "andy_1972 224".

Answer (score 0):

Using cut:

```
echo andy_1972 \* andy@ip.address 0 0 0 0 0 0 119075 224 1342751704 1348550270 |
    cut -d' ' -f1,10
```